# Changing the UIImage assigned to a UIImageView in an array

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray which I fill with UIImageViews like this:

```
NSMutableArray *digitArray;

spaces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:16];

[spaces addObject:space1];
[spaces addObject:space2];
[spaces addObject:space3];
[spaces addObject:space4];
[spaces addObject:space5];
[spaces addObject:space6];
[spaces addObject:space7];
[spaces addObject:space8];
[spaces addObject:space9];
[spaces addObject:space10];
[spaces addObject:space11];
[spaces addObject:space12];
[spaces addObject:space13];
[spaces addObject:space14];
[spaces addObject:space15];
[spaces addObject:space16];
```

I then assign an image to each of the UIImageViews, like this:

```
[(UIImageView *)spaces[0] setImage:one];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[1] setImage:two];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[2] setImage:three];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[3] setImage:four];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[4] setImage:five];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[5] setImage:six];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[6] setImage:seven];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[7] setImage:eight];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[8] setImage:nine];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[9] setImage:ten];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[10] setImage:eleven];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[11] setImage:twelve];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[12] setImage:thirteen];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[13] setImage:fourteen];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[14] setImage:fifteen];
[(UIImageView *)spaces[15] setImage:sixteen];
```

So with this as my default combination I then want to be able to randomly change which image is assigned with which UIImageVIew. Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

George

Comment: Surely you could just use a for loop instead of writing them out one by one like that?

Answer (score 0):

think this should do it

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while(space.count > 0){

    int index = arc4random_uniform(space.count);
    [temp addObject:[spaces objectAt:index]];
    [space removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}

spaces = temp;
```

havnt tested the code, but it takes 1 random ImageView from spaces and puts it into a temp array, then onces all the objects from spaces has been put into temp it assigns it back to spaces

Comment: i think he needs something more like 
`UIImageView *img1 = [spaces objectAtIndex:randomNumber1];
 UIImageView *img2 = [spaces objectAtIndex:randomNumber2];
 [img1 setImage:img2.image];`
And put this in loop

Comment: You could genrate the `randomNumber` using `rand()%16` assuming you have 16 images in the array and want a random index between 0-15

Comment: ah yes, misunderstood his question

Comment: I put that into a while loop but it only seems to swap two of them around at once. Surely this way would also mean that I will end up with numbers assigned to more than one UIImageView?

Comment: Cheers for the responses though guys!

Comment: so you basically just want to scramble the whole array? also i think you should probably use random() i think you need to use srand() before you use rand() otherwise it wont randomise properly

Comment: I don't need to change the position of the UIImageViews in the array, I just want to swap which image is assigned with each one.

Comment: does it matter if the imageViews swap places? ive updated my answer that should scramble the imageViews around. otherwise you can adapt it to just move the images from the image views around instead of the whole imageview, just easier this way if it doesnt matter

Comment: otherwise you should separate out the UIImageViews from the UIImages, have them in 2 separate arrays and randomise the one array, then assign the images to the imageViews afterwards

Comment: I've done it by creating the two separate arrays then mixing one up. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *firstImage = [spaces objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(16)];

UIImageView *secondImage = [spaces objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(16)];

UIImageView *tempImage = firstImage;

firstImage.image = secondImage.image;

secondImage.image = tempImage.image;
```

There might be a shorter way though. But this should do the trick. 
Random means, both images may be the same. That does not harm but effectively nothing will be changed then.

Comment: Surely this way means that the same number could be assigned to more than one UIImageView?

Comment: Yes. Then it is swaped with itself. But no harm is done. You may apply it and mend it a bit if he fells that this event should be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that's interested, I achieved what I was trying to by creating a second array called `numbers` and filled it with the images. I then randomised this second array:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    int j = arc4random() % 16;
    [numbers exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j];
}
```

I then assigned the images of the various UIImageViews in the first array as the images of the second array

```
     [(UIImageView *)spaces[0] setImage:numbers[0]];
     [(UIImageView *)spaces[1] setImage:numbers[1]];
     .... etc
```

Due to the mixing up of the numbers array, the contents of `numbers[0]` and `numbers[1]` etc, would be different each time.

Thanks everyone for your answers though!